# Use substitution $u=\cos(x^2/4)$ to find $\int_0^\sqrt{\pi} 2x\cos(x^2/4) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I found that $du=-x\sin(x^2/4)dx/2$ but this is way more complicated then the $u$ substitutions I have done. I am stuck and from here don't know what to do. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you obliged to use this substitution ?

Comment: Using $u=\sin(x^2/4)$ is much simpler...

Comment: @Claude Leibovici yes it specifically asks for it.

Comment: @user10354138 1. how did you get that. 2 the book gives you the u so you have to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}} 2x \cos (x^2/4) dx$$
Let $x^2/4=t \implies xdx=2dt$
Then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} 4 \cos t dt =4 \sin t|_{0}^{\pi/4}=2 \sqrt{2}$$

Now in OP's way: Let $\cos(x^2/4)=u \implies x dx=-\frac{2du}{\sin(x^2/4)}=\frac{-2udu}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$, then
$$I=-4\int_{1}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} du$$
Next, let $u^2=v$, then
$$I=-2\int_{1}^{1/2} \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v}} =4\sqrt{1-v}|_{1}^{1/2}=2\sqrt{2}. $$

Comment: how come the sin is in the denominator and not numerator in xdx isn't it dx/du?

Comment: @mary james Basically it is $-\frac{1}{2}x \sin(x^2/4) dx=du$.

Comment: oww i see so you did du/dx instead of dx/du what I did how do we know when to use du/dx and du/dx inaddition to how did you make$ {\sqrt{ pi }}$ into $ {1/\sqrt{2}}$ i am confused I cant use the easier method as the book specifically asks for this u. also how did this go into this $-\frac{2du}{\sin(x^2/4)}=\frac{-2udu}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$

Comment: $u =\cos(x^2/4), s0 \sin(x^2/4)=1-\cos^2(x^2/4) \implies \sin(x^2\pi/4)=\sqrt{1-u^2}$

Comment: owww i see thank you very much and the integer how did it go from  ${\sqrt{pi}}$ to ${\sqrt{1-u^2}}$

Comment: $\frac{2du}{\sin(x^2/4)}=\frac{-2udu}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ and how is there an extra u in the numerator in the second ? and what you just showed me where how can make it square i see how its u^2 but where did this square come from?

Comment: Becaues $\cos(x^2/4)$ is the integrand.

Comment: I am so so sorry i sometimes understand slowly but I don't get what you mean why did it square?

Answer (score 1):

Use $t=x^2/4$ to write the integral as $\int_0^{\pi/4}4\cos tdt$. As @user10354138 notes, $u=\sin t$ would help much more than $u=\cos t$: the integral is clearly $[4\sin t]_0^{\pi/4}=2\sqrt{2}$. If we instead use $u=\cos t$, we get$$\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1\frac{4u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=[-4\sqrt{1-u^2}]_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1=2\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: but it specifically asks for this u

Comment: @maryjames I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the hinted substitution:**

$$2\int x \cos\frac{x^2}4 dx=-4\int \frac{xu\,du}{x\sin\dfrac{x^2}4}=-4\int\frac{u\,du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=4\sqrt{1-u^2}=4\sin\frac{x^2}4.$$

Anyway, the substitution $u=\dfrac{x^2}4$ is preferred.

Comment: but is spesifacally asks for this u

Comment: @maryjames: I solved for the imposed $u$, why do you complain ?

Comment: owww i was confused the way you did it I am sorry its just the books answer is $2{\sqrt{2}}$